# LINQ GroupBy two object properties and SUM, AVG, or Ignore others using Lambda

Tags: linq, lambda, group-by, aggregate

I have List of objects that I would like to group together using LINQ Lambda syntax.

```
public class Candy
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Distributor {get; set;}
  public int Quantity {get; set;}
  public decimal UnitPrice {get; set;}
}
```

A sample collection `List<Candy>` might look like the following:

```
{ Id = "AF001", Name = "Atomic Fireball", Distributor = "Wonka Candy", Quantity = 100, UnitPrice = 1 }
{ Id = "AF001", Name = "Atomic Fireball", Distributor = "Slugworth Confections", Quantity = 300, UnitPrice = 2 }
{ Id = "GW001", Name = "Gummy Worm", Distributor = "Wonka Candy", Quantity = 200, UnitPrice = 2 }
{ Id = "GW001", Name = "Gummy Worm", Distributor = "Slugworth Confections", Quantity = 250, UnitPrice = 3 }
{ Id = "CG001", Name = "Cherry Gumball", Distributor = "Wonka Candy", Quantity = 30000, UnitPrice = 3 }
{ Id = "GF001", Name = "Grape Fizzy", Distributor = "Slugworth Confections", Quantity = 30000, UnitPrice = 1 }
```

I would like to use LINQ Lambda to group those items that have the same Id and Name. For those items that are grouped I would like to SUM the Quantity and AVERAGE the price. I would like to end up with a grouped set that looks like this.

```
{ Id = "AF001", Name = "Atomic Fireball", Distributor = "Wonka Candy", Quantity = 400, UnitPrice = 1.5 }
{ Id = "GW001", Name = "Gummy Worm", Distributor = "Wonka Candy", Quantity = 450, UnitPrice = 2.5 }
{ Id = "CG001", Name = "Cherry Gumball", Distributor = "Wonka Candy", Quantity = 30000, UnitPrice = 3 }
{ Id = "GF001", Name = "Grape Fizzy", Distributor = "Slugworth Confections", Quantity = 30000, UnitPrice = 1 }
```

I was thinking something like this, but I am unsure how to use the aggregate functions within LINQ.

```
List<Candy> ungroupedCandies = GetCandies();

List<Candy> groupedCandies = ungroupedCandies.GroupBy(
                                               c => c.Id,
                                               c => c.Name)
                                              .Select(NOT SURE HERE)
```

I would really like to stick with Lambda syntax rather than a query expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Grouping by multiple fields requires `new` with an anonymous type,
- Once you have your groups, select new `Candy` objects with computed fields,
- Averaging unit prices works only when all quantities are identical. You need to compute total price, and divide it by total quantity to find the average price.

Here is how you can do it:

```
var grouped = ungroupedCandies
    .GroupBy(c => new {c.Id, c.Name })
    .Select(g => new Candy {
        Id = g.Key.Id
    ,   Name = g.Key.Name
    ,   Distributor = g.First().Distributor
    ,   Quantity = g.Sum(c => c.Quantity)
    ,   UnitPrice = g.Sum(c => c.Quantity * c.UnitPrice) / g.Sum(c => c.Quantity)
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Note:** To see why averaging directly does not work, consider two groups of the same candy with `{Q=1, P=1}` and `{Q=999, P=2}`. Average price of the 1000 candies would be pretty close to 2, because a single "half-price" candy from the first group is not going to make a difference in the overall lot of 1000 candies.

Comment: Excellent example. Thank you. I am looking to average the UnitPrice without taking into consideration the Quantity. They are separate from each other. But in any case your example really helped out. Thanks!

Comment: @webworm You can use `Average` method of LINQ to compute simple averages, i.e. `g.Average(c => c.UnitPrice)`.

Comment: Thanks for also adding the `g.First().Distributor`. I wasn't sure how to pull that down into the collection. Very clear and easy to understand example.